# Problem setting shadowColor property on UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

```
NSString *imgPath = [[jsonObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"];
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgPath]];
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 7, 44, 44)];
img.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
img.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
img.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 2);
[cell addSubview:img];
[imgPath release];
[imgData release];
[img release];
```

When using this code, I get the following warning:

*Passing argument 1 of 'setShadowColor:' from incompatible pointer type*

The code compiles just fine and the image is shown correctly, but without a shadow.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I suppose it's a bit late.

It is as Dasdom already wrote :

```
img.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
img.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
img.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
```

But you have to ensure that the imageView is not clipped to its frame:

```
img.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
img.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

to

```
img.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```

and add

```
img.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
img.layer.shadowRadius = 8.0f;
```

Comment: Alright, now the warning is gone, but still no shadow. Maybe my approach isn't right?

Comment: Ok, try to change the shadowRadius to 2.0f.

Comment: Next (and last) idea: Try to put the image into a view and add a shadow to the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
sender.layer.shadowColor=[[UIColor yellowColor]CGColor];
sender.layer.shadowRadius=10;
sender.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(1, 1);
sender.layer.shadowOpacity=1;
```

here sender is `UIButton` type.